# How to add storage migration in parachain?

Tags: polkadot-js, parachain, storage, migration

I have successfully performed storage migration on standalone chain. But how to do this for parachain ?
Like, How/what wasm should be upload of new version and Where Should I upload ?
Is there any different process from standalone to do this ?

If I'm simply upload the upgraded wasm, the blocks remains finalising but **sudo.sudoUncheckedWeight
ready** : [image]
this process will not complete.
Can anyone please help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using compact.compressed wasm.

Answer (score -2):

what you want to do is use the sudo tab, then sudo > setCode(WithoutChecks)

Comment: Nothing Happen!, Same issue will occur even doing with setCode(WithoutChecks)

Comment: no, use the setCodeWithoutChecks function